# Why are all meta keys unbound in org-mode?

Tags: debugging, emacs, org-mode

I restarted Emacs recently and now all my keybindings that start with Meta, such as `M-x` and `M-q`, are unbound in `org-mode`. It is really weird because I tried to specifically define it in `org-mode` with

```
(org-defkey org-mode-map [(meta x)] 'execute-extended-command)
```

but I get the error:

```
Key sequence M-x starts with non-prefix key ESC
```

So that doesn't work to temporarily fix it, but the bigger problem is that I have no sense of where to start searching for why these things are unbound in `org-mode`.

I know it must be me, because `emacs -Q` and `emacs -q` don't have the problem.

Any clues or advice?

Comment: You should try `emacs -q` to make sure it's *your* init file that causes the problem (`-Q` avoids loading the site init file as well). Then bisect your way through: comment out roughly half of the prolbematic init file, then 3/4 of it, then 7/8 of it, ... until you zero in on the the problem.

Comment: What @NickD said. Also, if you see the same problem with regular `M-x`, i.e., without Helm, then remove Helm (and its tag) from your question, to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bound `C-[` to something and that took over `M-x`, because `M-x` is really `ESC x` and `ESC x` is really `C-[ x`.

`(org-defkey org-mode-map (kbd "C-[") 'org-metaleft)`

Comment: `M-x` is really `ESC x`, not just `ESC` - but yes, redefining prefix keys is bad :-)